# Password circle in kotlin simplified

Tags: android, kotlin

I currently do this to make my custom password circle:

```
val pinIcon0 = "◇ ◇ ◇ ◇"
val pinIcon1 = "◆ ◇ ◇ ◇"
val pinIcon2 = "◆ ◆ ◇ ◇"
val pinIcon3 = "◆ ◆ ◆ ◇"
val pinIcon4 = "◆ ◆ ◆ ◆"
```

And then do this:

```
listOf(num0,num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6,num7,num8,num9)
            .withIndex()
            .forEach { (index, view) ->
                view.setOnClickListener {
                    pinCount++
                    pinCodeNew.append("$index")

                    if(pinCount == 0){ newPinCircle.text = pinIcon0 }
                    if(pinCount == 1 || pinCount == 5){ newPinCircle.text = pinIcon1 }
                    if(pinCount == 2 || pinCount == 6){ newPinCircle.text = pinIcon2 }
                    if(pinCount == 3 || pinCount == 7){ newPinCircle.text = pinIcon3 }
                    if(pinCount == 4 || pinCount == 8){ newPinCircle.text = pinIcon4 }

                    if(pinCount == 8){
                        savePin()
                        newPinTxt.text = "NEW PIN"
                        newPinCircle.text = pinIcon0
                    }
                    if(pinCount == 9){
                        pinCount = 0
                        newPinCircle.text = pinIcon0
                    }
                    if(pinCount == 4){
                        if(pinCodeNew.text.toString() == "1234"){
                            Toast.makeText(this,"PIN cannot be 1234", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            pinCodeNew.text?.clear()
                            pinCount = 0
                            newPinCircle.text = pinIcon0
                        }else {
                            if(pinCodeNew.text.toString() == getEncryptedSharedPrefs().getString("pinSettingsLogin", "")){
                                Toast.makeText(this,"PIN cannot be current PIN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                pinCodeNew.text?.clear()
                                pinCount = 0
                                newPinCircle.text = pinIcon0
                            }else{
                                getEncryptedSharedPrefs().edit()
                                    .putString("pinSettingsNew", pinCodeNew.text.toString())
                                    .apply()
                                pinCodeNew.text?.clear()
                                newPinTxt.text = "CONFIRM PIN"
                                newPinCircle.text = pinIcon0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the current code I use to make my stuff happen good, but not optimal. The part that needs some work is the 5 "if" statements to change my pinIcon.

See image below here on what It looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This way you can loop through the list endlessly no need to worry about index getting out of range of list

```
var pinCount = 0
val pins = listOf("◇ ◇ ◇ ◇","◆ ◇ ◇ ◇","◆ ◆ ◇ ◇","◆ ◆ ◆ ◇","◆ ◆ ◆ ◆")
```

And in your click listener

```
newPinCircle.text = pins[pinCount]
pinCount = (pinCount +1) % pins.size
```

Answer (score 2):

you can exchange `pinCount == 1 || pinCount == 5` to `pinCount % 4 == 1` and also use `else` for preventing unnecessary `if` conditions checks (as they are excluding in fact). also in Kotlin you may use

```
newPinCircle.text = 
    if(pinCount % 4 == 1) pinIcon1
    else if(pinCount % 4 == 2) pinIcon2
    else if(pinCount % 4 == 3) pinIcon3
    else pinIcon4 // can pinCount be > 8?
```

besides these "improvements" you've posted veeery little code for more suggestions

I would suggest to make "beautiful" app and showing filled dots with text/characters won't be pretty for shure ;) Would look better with `ImageView`s with exchanging their images, even better it would be to use `checkable` attribute and some "filling" anims. But who knows how your layout looks like, what contains, for what it is used

Comment: This works good. One thing that doesn't work good is in my app I have after you typed 4 digits it counts these, so the pinCount is then 4, then you have to retype the 4 same digits to confirm a match, so the pinCount will be 8 at the end. But if you delete a digit when it's below pinCount 5 (which means 1 digit), it returns 4 full pinIcons, but in this case it should be 4 empty pinIcons. If you understand what I'm saying here

Comment: you should post more code and describe your case in question. you probably need some flag for setting that user already passed "first-4" digits and now ill again enter veryifying-4, probably you should reset `pinCount` then. but with posted code all is guessing

Comment: Yeah I added the whole thing including an image of what it looks like.

Comment: and what about "backspace button", what it does? is it manipulating `pinCount`? your code is simplified "to much", you should let entering 4 digits, recognizing are these "proper" (not "1234"), then resetting and counting again, after 4 digits comparing to previously set. currently you are trying to base your solution on one "global" variable `pinCount`, you won't do that, at least in "readable" way

Answer (score 0):

Basically you'd need the maximum length of the pin number and basically use some functional operators

```kotlin
fun onPinTyped() {
  editText.value = List<String>(MAX_PIN_LENGTH) { i ->  if(i <= pinCount) "◆" else "◇" }.joinToString(separator=" ")
}
```

What this bit of code is doing is essentially creating a list of strings with as many elements as a outer variable named `MAX_PIN_LENGTH`.

It then executes the function for each of the elements (ie, characters) that are going to compose your text.

The function returns `◆` for all characters that have already been typed and `◇` for the missing ones.

Lastly it joins each of the separater characters into a single string separating each character with a whitespace.

This code is not the most efficient one due to unneeded string allocations but hey, it's a one-liner.

---

A more optimal approach is to use the `buildString` utility from the `kotlin.text` package:

```kotlin
fun onPinTyped() {
  editText.value = buildString {
    (0..MAX_PIN_LENGTH).forEach { i ->
       append(if(i<=pinCount) '◆' else '◇')
    }
  }
}
```